How to make a date input match a certain day of the week?
I have an HTML script with date inputs for each day of the week (Sunday-Saturday). I'd like to validate the inputs so that the user can only select dates which match that day of the week. For example, December 1, 2024 was a Sunday, so the user can only input December 1, 8, 15, 22, etc into that box. They cannot input December 2 or 3.
<table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="date">Sunday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Monday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Tuesday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Wednesday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Thursday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Friday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Saturday:</label></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<table>

This script where getDay() returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) of a date.
<p id="date1"></p>

const weekday = new Date("December 01, 2024 01:15:00");
let day = weekday.getDay()

document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = day;

The script below returns an alert every time a date selected (including Sundays). And if I add else it does not return an alert at all (including Mondays-Saturdays). However I may be inserting the else incorrectly.
function validateDate(date) {
    const selectedDate = new Date(date);
    const day = selectedDate.getDay();
    if (day !== 0) {
        alert("Please select a date that falls on a Sunday.");}
}

Thank you in advance

"The script below returns an alert every time a date selected" - why/how, what is calling validateDate?

(Your label's for attributes make no sense. This needs to contain an element id.)

If adding an else clause did not work, that attempted code should be included in the question.

@C3roe Nothing was calling it before (I'm new to this). I've now added the function to inline with the date input. Is that how I call it? It still gives an alert every time. <input name="date" type="text" id="date1" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}" onchange="validateDate()">.

@C3roe I also added id elements to the labels - thanks

onchange="validateDate()" - that's not going to pass any date parameter to the function. Make that onchange="validateDate(this.value)", so that it passes the current field value to the function.

@C3roe Thanks that worked! That was the missing piece, and adding the corresponding day-of-the-week number. onchange="validateDate(this.value, 0)" for Sunday, etc. Thanks for your help - I appreciate your explanations and suggestions a lot.

Click validate all to check wrong inputs.


function validateDate() {
let el=document.querySelectorAll(".dateInputCLS");
for(let a=0;a<el.length;a++){
    let dateOBJ = new Date(el[a].value);
    let day = dateOBJ.getDay();
    if (day !== a){el[a].style.border="2px solid red";}
    else{el[a].style.border="2px solid black";}
}
}
.dateInputCLS{border:2px solid black;}
<table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="date">Sunday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Monday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Tuesday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Wednesday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Thursday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Friday:</label></td>
  <td><label for="date">Saturday:</label></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
  <td><input class="dateInputCLS" name="date" type="text" style="width:130px" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value){this.type='text';this.style.width='130px'}"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<table>

<button onclick="validateDate();">Validate All</button>




The value of a Date input is format YYYY-MM-DD, which is parsed as UTC but getDay returns the local day. So the validation will be incorrect for the period of the system local offset from midnight. Fixed by using getUTCDay. :-) Consider let validateDate = () => document.querySelectorAll('.dateInputCLS').forEach((el, i) => el.style.borderColor = new Date(el.value).getUTCDay() == i? 'black' : 'red');.
